# Called with null table in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am getting some odd looking errors after a crash on my app, after the crash Xcode presented a pop up saying `app quit unexpectedly` with the following messages in the console:

```
2021-11-11 11:08:59.305895-0600 [9423:1165548] [] __nwlog_err_simulate_crash simulate crash already simulated "nw_hash_table_apply called with null table"
2021-11-11 11:08:59.306403-0600 [9423:1165548] [] nw_hash_table_apply called with null table, dumping backtrace:
        [arm64] libnetcore-2736.12.1
    0   libnetwork.dylib                    0x0000000182b599c0 __nw_create_backtrace_string + 120
    1   libnetwork.dylib                    0x00000001822d387c nw_hash_table_apply + 2808
    2   libnetwork.dylib                    0x000000018285b1e4 D810C689-1339-3FC6-96E8-196B9901E4DC + 6300132
    3   libnetwork.dylib                    0x0000000182858cc0 D810C689-1339-3FC6-96E8-196B9901E4DC + 6290624
    4   CFNetwork                           0x0000000182004ff4 _CFURLStorageSessionCopyIdentifier + 20652
    5   libnetwork.dylib                    0x00000001823f8da4 D810C689-1339-3FC6-96E8-196B9901E4DC + 1703332
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010adb0a20 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010adb2700 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010adbce34 _dispatch_workloop_invoke + 2960
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010adc7fa0 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 916
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001f114d1b0 _pthread_wqthread + 288
    11  libsystem_pthread.dylib
```

And:

```
2021-11-11 11:09:25.449348-0600 [9423:1165132] [connection] nw_read_request_report [C4] Receive failed with error "Software caused connection abort"
```

Not really sure what this means and what's causing it, I also couldn't find any good info on it.

Comment: Related? https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/693133

Comment: Going by its name, `nw_hash_table_apply` is probably similar to [`xpc_dictionary_apply`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xpc/1505404-xpc_dictionary_apply), but for an "nw_hash" (Likely a dictionary type, that's internal to libnetwork). They're trying to call it on a null dictionary. This looks like a bug in libnetwork.